# CreateMutex() returns ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED on Win 10 but not on Win 7

Tags: windows, namespaces, mutex, global-namespace

I have 2 windows programs one that runs at Session 0 and another at Session 1.
Both programs creates the same named mutex with the 'Global\' namespace prefix,
Session 0 creates first and when Session 1 tries to createMutex, I get ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED error on windows 10 but it works fine on windows 7.
The mutex permissions\security attribute\code looks the same on both OS.

1. I know how to fix this but i'm interested of knowing why is there a difference between windows 7 and 10 behavior? 
   I think win 10 behavior is the right one, the mutex is created with no permissions for my user...
2. Can it be that the permission 'CREATOR OWNER' is different between the OS? how can i "echo CREATOR OWNER"?
3. Global\Local namespace influences only sharing\separate between sessions? or there's more?

Thanks!!!

**UPDATE**:

I found the difference between windows 7 and 10 which cause this.
Checking the process properties via Process Explorer i can see "Deny" flag vs "Owner" flag on Win7 (picture below).

1. What is this flag? How do i change it? What do i google for information about it?
2. Does the default settings for this really changed between the OS?

[image]